# TextView is blank until activity is restarted

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This code is supposed to change values of the textviews on starting the activity. But it does not. I need to restart the activity manualy. Please help me.

```
package com.example.chinmay.departmentalapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class StudentDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView rollNo, name, contact1, contact2, avg;
Intent i;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    i = getIntent();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_details);

    rollNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rollNo);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.studName);
    contact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact1);
    contact2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact2);
    avg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgPresenty);

    rollNo.setText(i.getStringExtra("roll"));
    name.setText(i.getStringExtra("name"));
    contact1.setText(i.getStringExtra("contact"));
    contact2.setText(i.getStringExtra("con2"));
    avg.setText(i.getStringExtra("avgPres"));
}
}
```

`StudentDetails.java` looks like this. I tried to solve it but evertything failed. I dont know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: expound restart manually?

Comment: i meant i need to go back to previous activity screen and when i start again from there it works

Comment: How do u start StudentDetails Acvtity? Could u pls post code snippet.

Comment: i edited the post. plese check :)

Comment: textViews might be blank because there is extra data in intent and every `i.getStringExtra()` returns `null`.

There is no problem with this activity code. The problem might be from where you send data to this activity. So please share code from where you are starting `StudentDetails` activity.

Comment: Sorry for wrong statement in above comment. TextViews might be blank because there is NO extra data in intent and every `i.getStringExtra()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code below and this will work fine i hope so

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
i.getIntent()
```

After

```
super.oncreate()
setContentView()
```

Because this activity is created after

```
super.oncreate()
```

is called. For first execution activity is not created when getting the intent. The problem is you are trying to get intent in an activity which has not yet been created. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: i had tried this but the problem repeats. i just kept getIntent before onCreate so that i can get the intent right when the activity starts

Comment: Did you check that the values are getting initialized  by displaying in log

Comment: Yup this answer is right you have to get data from `intent` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: @AdityaSonel I alredy tried it but it's not helping